# Unable to not print the stop value of the loop

Tags: python

I am trying to stop the loop at number 237 and print all the numbers in the list before it that are even numbers but it keeps printing 237 out

Putting <= 237 prints 2 values only and putting >= 238 prints out a few more numbers in the list

```py
numbers = [386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345, 
    399, 162, 758, 219, 918, 237, 412, 566, 826, 248, 866, 950, 626, 949, 687, 217, 
    815, 67, 104, 58, 512, 24, 892, 894, 767, 553, 81, 379, 843, 831, 445, 742, 717, 
    958,743, 527]

number = numbers.sort()

for x in numbers:
    if x %2 == 0:
        print(x)
    elif x >= 237:
        break

print(x)
```

Comment: Seems that you print(x) after the for loop too?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do

```
if x == 237:
    break
```

It still print 237, because in your last line you do print x, but when your loop break, 237 is assigned to x.

Comment: It still prints out 237 for some reason

Comment: @PyNewb Yeah cause you `print(x)` after the loop

Comment: you could simply do a lot of things but it doesn't really change whether or not x gets printed out twice

Answer (score 0):

use this code instead, code will only run when x<237

```
numbers.sort()
for x in numbers:
    if x<237:
        if x %2 == 0:
            print(x)
    else:
        break
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to print the value before 237 I suggest you keep the last value to a variable.

```
numbers = [386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345, 399, 162, 758, 219, 918, 237, 412, 566, 826, 248, 866, 950, 626, 949, 687, 217, 815, 67, 104, 58, 512, 24, 892, 894, 767, 553, 81, 379, 843, 831, 445, 742, 717, 958,743, 527]

number = numbers.sort()
y = ''
for x in numbers:
    if x >= 237:
        print(y)
        break
    elif x %2 == 0:
        print(x)
        y = x
```

Comment: You can’t just assume that the list order can be changed.

Answer (score -1):

```
numbers = [    
    386, 462, 47, 418, 907, 344, 236, 375, 823, 566, 597, 978, 328, 615, 953, 345, 
    399, 162, 758, 219, 918, 237, 412, 566, 826, 248, 866, 950, 626, 949, 687, 217, 
    815, 67, 104, 58, 512, 24, 892, 894, 767, 553, 81, 379, 843, 831, 445, 742, 717, 
    958,743, 527
    ]

for x in numbers:
    if x == 237:
        break

    if x % 2 == 1:
        continue

    print(x)
```

I hope it's helpful for you.
Thank you.

Comment: What if your list has values higher than 237 only